# Maxmin sum of squares construction

Tags: geometry

> In triangle ABC construct thru B a line so that the sum of squared
>   distances from A and C to this line was MAX, MIN, or a given p*p.

How to do this construction?

Comment: This is not a question, are you asking how to do it?

Comment: Yes, how to construct?

Comment: What is $p$?...

Comment: p is just a length of a line segment. There are 3 questions here:
1. Construct a line thru B so that the sum of squares is MAX.
2. Construct the line so that the sum of squares is MIN.
3. Construct the line so that the sum of squares is equal to p*p.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = Ax^2 + By + C$ be a quadratic curve with $A > 0$.

Fact-1: $A>0$ implies the curve concaves upward with a minimum occurs when $x = \frac {–B} {2A}$.

Fact-2: Intuitively, the above curve attains its maximum when $x -> ±∞$.

-----[For simplicity, we restrict ourselves to $+∞$ only.]

Consider figure 1:-
[image]

WLOG, we can assume $AC = 1$ unit. Let the required line be BP where is P divides CA internally in the ratio $CP : PA = x : (1 – x)$.

By similar triangles, $d_1 = kx$ and $d_2 = k(1 – x)$ for some non-zero proportional constant k.

∴ $D = d_1^2 + d_2^2 = k^2x^2 + k^2(1 – x)^2 = … = 2k^2x^2 – 2k^2x + k^2$; which is quadratic with ‘A’ > 0.

Applying fact-1, we have the min(D) is at $x = … = 1/2$. 
That is, P is midway between A and C.

[**If the red line is drawn outside the triangle, the result is the same by using a similar approach.]

For max(D), we use fact-2.

Geometrically, x is infinitely produced such that CA and BP will never meet.

That is, BP // CA. (See figure 2.)

Thus, $max(D) = …= 2h_B^2$; where $h_B$ is the altitude from B to CA (produced if necessary).

As for the $D = p^2$ part, I am still seeking help. See [problem #688841](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688841/determining-the-location-of-a-point-in-a-triangle-under-the-given-constraints).

Comment: @rafi Your problem has been 'buried' over 18 month. Hope the above late suggestion can be of some help.